# jQuery ajax call not triggering success function on Safari 9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In a project I have a particular ajax call that works fine on PC Chrome/Firefox, but on Safari 9.1 it fails to trigger the success function.

The ajax call:

```
$('#new_file_form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/includes/ajax/file-manager.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    JSON.parse(result);
                    alert(result);
                    if (result == true) {
                        $('#new_file_form').reset;
                        $('#new_file_modal').modal('hide');
                        bootbox.alert({
                            size: 'small',
                            message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign blue"></i>File successfully saved.',
                            callback: function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (result == false) {
                        bootbox.alert({
                            size: 'small',
                            message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign orange"></i>File not saved.',
                            callback: function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        bootbox.alert({
                            size: 'small',
                            message: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign orange"></i>Whoa! That escalated quickly..',
                            callback: function() {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
```

This doesn't throw any errors. The file is uploaded and the data inserted into the database, it's just the success function that sits there and seems to be laughing at me.

Based on the returned error in Safari it seems useful to post the file-manager.php code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['file_name']) && !empty($_POST['file_type']) && !empty($_POST['file_user'])) { // && !empty($_FILES['file'])
    $ownerid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['file_user']);
    $ownertype = 1;
    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['file_name']);
    $visible = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['visible']);
    $filetype = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['file_type']);

    $ownerid = filter_var($ownerid, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $visible = filter_var($visible, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $filetype = filter_var($filetype, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    $cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $edate = $cdate;

    $u_file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $u_tmp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $u_file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $u_file_error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $u_file_content = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    $upload_result = '';

    if($u_file_error == 'UPLOAD_ERROR_OK') {
        if($u_file_name == '') {
            $upload_result = false;
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT path FROM filetypes WHERE id = '$filetype'";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
            $record = $result->fetch_object();
            $file_type_path = $record->path;

            $extension = end(explode(".", $u_file_name));
            if($ownertype == 1) {
                $s_file_name = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", $name).'-'.date('Y-m-d_H-i').'.'.$extension;
                $s_file_dest = LOCAL_BASE_PATH.'/uploads/'.$ownerid.'/'.$file_type_path;
                $s_file_location = $s_file_dest.'/'.$s_file_name;
                $s_file_path = '/uploads/'.$ownerid.'/'.$file_type_path.$s_file_name;
            }
            if(!file_exists($s_file_dest)) {
                mkdir($s_file_dest, 0755, true);
            }
            move_uploaded_file($u_tmp_file, $s_file_location);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO files (ownertype, owner, type, visible, extension, name, path, cdate, edate) VALUES ('$ownertype', '$ownerid', '$filetype', '$visible', '$extension', '$s_file_name', '$s_file_path', '$cdate', '$edate')";
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

            $upload_result = true;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($upload_result);
    exit();
}
```

When I alert the ajax result before parsing it, I get a PHP error: 
**Strict Standards**: Only variables should be passed by reference...

Comment: I've just replicated this form/script on my browser (Safari 9.1) and it seems to work. Are you getting any reports in Safari's Error Console?

Comment: Yes it does return "SyntaxError JSON Parse error: unrecognized token.

Comment: Try to check your response JSON => http://jsonlint.com/ Can you post it here?

Comment: check following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785404/jquery-ajax-responce-not-working-in-safari-but-other-browser-it-is-work-fine-w

Comment: another one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177407/jquery-ajax-function-not-working-in-safari-firefox-chrome-ie-okay

Comment: for testing I removed the parsing of the ajax result and added the alerted result to the question.